# I keep getting Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds (Firestore)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The app doesn't connect to the Firestore backend.

I keep getting a log error in my app.

> Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within
>   10 seconds
>        This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline
>   mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

The weird thing is that I only get this error when using a physical device when testing my app. The emulator doesn't have this issue I have no idea if this issue is a device specific thing or what But, I nearly tried everything and still no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connection on the device?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: did you find anything about it i keep getting this error while my connection speed is good